# Exact match for isearch

Tags: regular-expressions, isearch

I am relatively new to emacs. I am looking for a way to do the "exact match" type of interactive search. For example, search string "abcDEF" in following text should ***only*** match with ***line1's*** text:

- line1->   sometext_followed_by_space **abcDEF** sometext_preceded_by_space
- line2->   sometext_followed_by_space *.abcDEF* sometext_preceded_by_space
- line3->   sometext_followed_by_space *abcdef* sometext_preceded_by_space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are apparently looking for *word* search with case-sensitivity.

For case-sensitive search, set **`case-fold-search`** to `nil`.

You can also just toggle case-sensitivity temporarily, during Isearch, using **`M-c`**.

For incremental word search, use **`M-s w`**. For nonincremental word search, use **`M-s w RET`**.

There are additional ways to do word search. See the Emacs manual, node [Word Search](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Word-Search.html).

---

Strike that, for you apparently do not want to find `abcDEF` when it follows `.`.  So you want something different from word search.

In that case, use regexp search, looking for whitespace followed by word-constituent characters, e.g. **`C-M-s [[:space:]]abcDEF`**.

---

That includes the whitespace in the search hit. If you want to be able to see the word itself highlighted differently from the total match, use library [`isearch+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) and search with this: **`C-M-s [[:space:]]\(abcDEF\)`**. Isearch+ highlights each regexp group (e.g. `\(...\)`) differently.